# Adding values after the last element in two arrays

Tags: c, arrays

This program continuously asks for user input in pairs of doubles and stops when the user enters CTRL-D. I simply want to add the pair 1 and 0 into arrays a and b, respectively.

I use an interger j to keep track of how many spots are currently occupied by the pairs. Then afterwards I can increment j to add the 1 0 pair, but as you can see by the output screenshot, the 1 and 0 aren't added. What am I doing incorrect?

Note: The 1 0 pair has to be added after the user has entered CTRL-D, not while they are giving input.

```
int main()
{
    double a[20];  //Used to represent the 'a' in a + bi.
    double b[20];  //Used to represent the 'b' in a + bi.
    int j=0, n=0;
    while((scanf("%lf %lf", &a[j], &b[j]))==2){
        j++;
        n++;
    }

    printf("Before\n");
    for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
        printf("%f %f\n", a[k], b[k]);
    }

    printf("J: %d, N: %d\n", j, n);
    j++;
    n++;
    printf("J: %d, N: %d\n", j, n);

    a[j] = 1.0;
    b[j] = 0.0;

    printf("After\n");
    for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
        printf("%f %f\n", a[k], b[k]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY6mb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `j`, `n` to record how many times does the user input.
for example if I input : 
    1 2
    3 4
    5 6
    7 8

your `a` and `b` will be:

```
a[0] = 1 ; b[0] = 2
a[1] = 3 ; b[1] = 4
a[2] = 5 ; b[2] = 6
a[3] = 7 ; b[3] = 8
```

your `j` and `n` will be 4

Since you want to add `1` and `0` to the last elements of two arrays, there is no
need in `j++` and `n++` there, simply use `a[j] = 1.0` and `b[j] = 0.0(a[4] = 1.0, b[4] = 0.0)`